# little endian to big endian

Tags: c, memory, endianness

see

i have already written one library (on `little endian` machine)it works fine in little endian machine now i when i run in **in `big endian` platform it doesn't works** .error are very hard to understand.
Now i have understood the concept of `endianess` but still i am not getting...

```
i want to know for making ma library for `big-endian` which changes should i 
take care in ma code?
```

i wan to know which operation does have different behaviour in both endian

Comment: Probably need to give more information about what you were doing in your library. For example any network communications would be in conflict on for little endian / big endian

Comment: no i m not doing any network communication stuff...

Comment: Do you expect us to guess until you say "Yes, I'm doing this"? What is your library doing? What are the errors you get? What have you tried so far to find the source of the errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of things might need to be changed (it's difficult to give a comprehensive list: "this is what could go wrong").

Generally endianness issues arise when one tries to access directly the contents of the memory of an integer (say with `memcpy` for example, `union` tricks etc).

Comment: Don't forget shift operations, pointer arithmetic, type conversion just to name a few more. But you're correct WAY too many issues to guess what his particular problem could be unless he tells us.

Comment: @JesusRamos - Wrong. The operations you mention are all endian-safe, barring *pointer* conversions. Shifts: `(n>>1)<n&&n<(n<<1)` for any non-overflowing positive `n`. As far as pointer arithmetic is concerned: `(&a[n])<(&a[n+1])` holds for any valid pointer `a`. Type conversion is also safe unless you're doing pointer casts that would require `reinterpret_cast` in C++. `char b[4];int i=*(int*)(b);` is not endian-safe, but the more common `int i=(int)((long)1);` is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the issue cnicutar mentions, a typical candidate for issues is when you directly access parts of a type by an array of a different type, instead of using calculations for access.

```
unsigned long int  a = 0x04030201ul;

/* Directly accesses the representation, gives 2 on LE and 3 on BE */
b = ((unsigned char *)&a)[1];

/* Works with the values, always gives 2 */
b = (a >> 8) & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your library using binary data files?

When using binary files you have to take care in which format (big vs. little endian) you are writing/reading your data. For instance when writing an array of integers to a file they will be stored in the endianess of the machine that does the writing. When reading you have to take this circumstance into account and convert the data if necessary.